# Reloading data from a store in ExtJS 4

Tags: extjs, grid, refresh, store, reload

I have a store:

```
var store = new Ext.data.store({
                autoLoad: true,
                autoSync: true,
                model: 'myModel',
                proxy: {
                    type: 'rest',
                    url: '/url/to/my/json/encoded/results',
                    reader: {
                        type: 'json',
                        root: 'results'
                    },
                    writer: {
                        type:'json'
                    }
                }
            });
```

Which is the store for some grid in which I display those results.
My grid is configured as follows:

```
var myGrid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
                id:'myGridID',
                layout:'anchor',
                border:false,
                title:'My Grid',
                width:412,
                store:store,
                heigth:300,
                frame:false,
                .... etc
```

At some point I add an entry to my database, which works just fine (if I reload the page I see the newly added record in my grid). 
What I want to do is reload the grid so when I save that entry into my database the store and the grid refresh themselves and display the newly added record without me having to reload the whole page again.

I tried:

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getStore().reload();
```

and...

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getStore().load();
```

and...

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getView().refresh();
```

and I also tried setting the store as Ext.data.JsonStore but it does nothing.

But nothing works, I've been searching all over the internet for this unsuccessfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to run just: `myGrid.getStore().load();`

Comment: `Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getStore().load();` should work

Comment: Maybe it does reload the store, but still I have to reload the web page to see the new record in the grid

Comment: `Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getView().refresh()` should work.

Comment: Maybe it does reload the store, but still I have to reload the web page to see the new record in the grid

Comment: What browser? It's possible to use firebug to check out what the store load is returning.

Comment: firefox, I'll check and come back to you

Comment: I managed to update the grid, the only problem now is that when I reload the grid it shows a column that is supposed to be hidden

Comment: How did you hide that column, through the columnmodel? if you don't want column in there, don't define a column for that in the columnmodel. it would be helpful if you could post the entire code when you instantiate the gridpanel

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should definitely work:

```
Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getStore().load();
```

Are you getting any javascript errors when you use the above syntax? If so, seeing the specific error message might give some clues.

Also, ALWAYS ALWAYS use Chrome developer tools (or Firebug or IE Developer Toolbar if you love Firefox/IE). In this case, you want to see if an AJAX request is going out to /url/to/my/json/encoded/results.  That will at least tell you if the call to refresh the store is making it to your server.

My guess is that it's not, and you most likely have an error message being generated. Probably something along the lines of "Cannot call method 'getStore' of undefined"

This would at least let you know that you're not successfully obtaining a reference to your grid. From there, check to make sure that you didn't duplicate "myGridID" for another element or something silly like that.

You can output some info to the Chrome developer tools console to help debug, starting with:

```
console.log(Ext.getCmp('myGridID'));
```

See if it's undefined, or returns a references to the grid. If it's undefined then you're probably either duplicating the id, or maybe attempting to reload the grid before the component has actually been created (seeing your code in a bigger context of your application would help determine that).

If it successfully returns a reference to the grid component, then keep going down the line:

```
console.log(Ext.getCmp('myGridID').getStore());
```

Anyway, that's probably way too much explanation for something you've probably already solved by now. Maybe it will be helpful to someone else though.

Answer (score 9):

Try this it worked for me
tested on version **3.x**

> *Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').store.load();*

also you can use

> *Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').store.reload();*

if you want to pass parameters with the load store request

> *Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').store.load({params: {paramName:
>   paramValue}});*    *Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').store.reload({params:
>   {paramName: paramValue}});*

Answer (score 2):

if you want to reload your data, you must see the changes. I means, put this codes together:

```
 Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').getStore().load();
 Ext.getCmp('idMyGrid').getView().refresh();
```

This it's work for me. I hope that works for you too.

From Chile chorizo,
Saluds.

Answer (score 0):

see my code:

> var response = Ext.decode(result); // JSON from somewhere
>
> store.proxy = new Ext.ux.data.PagingMemoryProxy(response);
>
> grid.store = store;
>
> store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: 20} });
>
> grid.getView().refresh();